# JSONSchema validation for optional types

Tags: node.js, json-schema-validator

As of now I am using this in my jsonschema

```
"ApplicationContent": {
    "type": "string",
    "pattern": ".+"
},
```

My NodeJS code has

```
applicationContent: string | Record<string, unknown>;
```

How to write a jsonschema validation for validating the applicationContent variable.

Comment: Can you clarify how you want to validate it??

Comment: I wanted to validate both string and Record (in nodejs) Map (in java).

Comment: If you have a better answer, please do suggest, I think I have cracked it.

Answer (score 1):

The schema below validates for both "string" and for "Record<string, object>"

```
"ApplicationContent": {
    "type": ["string", "object"],
    "additionalProperties": { "type": "string" },
    "pattern": ".+"
  },
```

Comment: No need to use the pattern if you accept any character but otherwise the schema seems good

Comment: Im using com.github.fge.jsonschema.report.ProcessingReport to validate schema, does not seem to work without the above. I tried pattern only.

Comment: `pattern: .+` is equivalent to any string value of 1 or more length.  The same can be written  as `type: string, minLength: 1`   I'm not familiar with that package though so maybe it doesn't evaluate it in that way.